# How to get the record ID in field array?

Tags: ionic-framework, appery.io

Can you help me with this please? I use the IONIC 5 framework and Appery.io platform in order to build my app.

I displayed the list of data from my REST API and was able to display it in the page together with the record ID. I want to update the selected record using the record ID but I cannot get the correct value. [cid:9e3c9913-c781-4103-ac5b-e4ac7b3ca340]
In the [image: image above], I want to get the value of the selected record which is 278 how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the selected item's ID on the select event https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-4-events-and-actions#action-arguments

It is available in the variable *currentItem.itemValue*